# How to see output from a hidden cmd.exe?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

Whilst running an installer of our own product, a cmd.exe running a batch file has got stuck for some unknown reason - probably asking a prompt about overwriting a file, or similar. This cmd.exe is visible in task manager or process explorer, but has no window (we ran it that way...).

Is there a way to see what it has output anyway, so we can figure out why it got stuck?

Process explorer can at least show me the parameters passed to cmd.exe.

OS: Windows XP SP3, 32 bit.
Our Wise installer.exe is running cmd.exe, running a batch file, which is trying to runn the SQL Server 2008R2 installer.

Comment: So... you want to see previous output of a running program?

Comment: You'll have to change the script to pipe all output to a text file, but as for existing output, nothing doing.

Comment: Bob: yes basically ... as if it had a console window up.

Comment: @RandolphWest: so because there's no console window, it's essentially gone to the bitbucket?

Comment: @O'Rooney As far as I know, console output in this kind of situation is not retrievable. Someone might prove me wrong. What you could do is, as Randolph said, log output to a temporary text file at all times and delete that log file as the last step in the installation (or even keep it somewhere). That way, if an installation fails, you can get the client to send you the log file.

Comment: Yeah ... generally we do that, I guess this batch file was considered "too small too fail" :)

Comment: Windows now rebooted for an automatic update so the point is moot anyway...